# ORC Partition table insertion from HIVE managed partition table in HIVE

Tags: hive

Anyone, know how to query a ORC Partition table insertion from Hive managed table with partitions. I am failing to do so. And even after inserting the new partitions for the HIVE ORC table, i could not query it using SELECT and WHERE …!

below is my query details:

```
>DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mydb.loan_orc;
>CREATE TABLE mydb.loan_orc
(<NON PARTITION COLUMNS DEFINITION>)
PARTITIONED BY(<PARTITION COLUMNS DEFINITION>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
stored AS orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="NONE","orc.stripe.size"="67108864","orc.row.index.stride"="25000");
>INSERT INTO TABLE mydb.loan_orc 
PARTITION (<PARTITION COLUMNS>) 
SELECT <NON PARTITION COLUMNS>
FROM mydb.loan WHERE <PARTITION COLUMN CONDITIONS>;
```

loan table is the replica of loan_orc, but only difference is storage formats among Non ORC and ORC..!

Comment: You need to elaborate on the nature of your fail, error message , how you are querying etc...

Comment: mccainz, i have updated my question now... have a re look into it..!

Answer (score 0):

By executing below query my problem got resolved.

> set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
>
> INSERT INTO TABLE mydb.loan_orc PARTITION (='', ='', ='') select `(<partcol1>|<partcol2>|<partcol3>)?+.+` FROM mydb.loan where ='' AND ='' AND ='' limit 10;